# Healthcheck status based on underlying healthcheck

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Anyone know if I can set the 'main' health check status based on the underlying health checks in .net core 2.2 and/or 3.0?

I have a solution with some underlying dependencies with different dependency levels. Meaning that if one of them is Unhealthy I'd like to return Unhealthy for the status, but when another is unhealthy I only would like it to be degraded.

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<ImportantDependency>("Important")
    .AddCheck<NotAsImportantDependency>("Not that important");
```

So, when the ImportantDependency is Unhealthy I'd like my status to be Unhealthy but then the NotAsImportantDependency is Unhealthy the status can be Degraded.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 and +, you can do the following:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<ImportantDependency>("Important")
    .AddCheck<NotAsImportantDependency>(
        "Not that important",
        failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0#register-health-check-services